# Creating relational database tables for online exam portal

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm creating a online exam portal.

In the database I can represent the question and answers in two ways:

1. A Question table and a  Answer table with a One to Many relation between the Question and answer.
2. Question table with columns for each answers .

A question can have max. four options.

Which design out of 1 and 2 is better ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 is better. It is simple normalization. With option 2, for instance you would have 4 different column names and you would need statements like:

```
WHERE "this answer" = column1 OR "this answer" = column2 ... etc.
```

Very ugly and annoying. It would get worse where you wanted to put an index on the column but you don't here.

Furthermore relational databases are designed to work with normalised design, here with a one-to-many relationship. You will find much more support when you go looking to modify it especially if you add attributes to each answer.